# from sun application server to glassfish 3

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, glassfish, ejb-3.0

I am trying to migrate an java enterprise application from sun application server to glassfish 3.1.2, I have built the project from netbeans, but I have had many problems, next you can view my present problem:

```
ADVERTENCIA: DPL8004: file open failure; file = file:/C:/Documents%20and%20Settings/gespitto900814094/Mis%20documentos/Tecnocom/Leonardo/SIN-SVN/SVN/dist/gfdeploy/Master-Antares/Master-Antares-ejb_jar/co/gov/banrep/antares/utils/persistencia.rar
ADVERTENCIA: error in opening zip file --  archivo comprimido no válido: file:/C:/Documents%20and%20Settings/gespitto900814094/Mis%20documentos/Tecnocom/Leonardo/SIN-SVN/SVN/dist/gfdeploy/Master-Antares/Master-Antares-ejb_jar/co/gov/banrep/antares/utils/persistencia.rar
ADVERTENCIA: DPL8004: file open failure; file = file:/C:/Documents%20and%20Settings/gespitto900814094/Mis%20documentos/Tecnocom/Leonardo/SIN-SVN/SVN/dist/gfdeploy/Master-Antares/Master-Antares-ejb_jar/co/gov/banrep/antares/utils/persistencia.rar
ADVERTENCIA: error in opening zip file --  archivo comprimido no válido: file:/C:/Documents%20and%20Settings/gespitto900814094/Mis%20documentos/Tecnocom/Leonardo/SIN-SVN/SVN/dist/gfdeploy/Master-Antares/Master-Antares-ejb_jar/co/gov/banrep/antares/utils/persistencia.rar
GRAVE: Excepción al desplegar la aplicación [Master-Antares]
GRAVE: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.deploy.shared.InputJarArchive$ArchiveJarEntrySource.<init>(InputJarArchive.java:573)
    at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.deploy.shared.InputJarArchive$ArchiveJarEntrySource.<init>(InputJarArchive.java:565)
    at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.deploy.shared.InputJarArchive.createEntryEnumeration(InputJarArchive.java:443)
    at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.deploy.shared.InputJarArchive.entries(InputJarArchive.java:196)
    at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.deploy.shared.InputJarArchive.access$100(InputJarArchive.java:73)
    at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.deploy.shared.InputJarArchive$1.enumeration(InputJarArchive.java:159)
    at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.deploy.shared.InputJarArchive$CollectionWrappedEnumeration.<init>(InputJarArchive.java:716)
    at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.deploy.shared.InputJarArchive.getDirectories(InputJarArchive.java:154)
    at org.glassfish.deployment.common.DeploymentUtils.isEARFromIntrospecting(DeploymentUtils.java:338)
    at org.glassfish.deployment.common.DeploymentUtils.isEAR(DeploymentUtils.java:326)
    at org.glassfish.deployment.common.DeploymentUtils.hasResourcesXML(DeploymentUtils.java:255)
    at org.glassfish.deployment.common.DeploymentUtils.hasResourcesXML(DeploymentUtils.java:268)
    at com.sun.enterprise.connectors.connector.module.ResourcesCompositeSniffer.handles(ResourcesCompositeSniffer.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.internal.deployment.GenericCompositeSniffer.handles(GenericCompositeSniffer.java:80)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.SnifferManagerImpl.getCompositeSniffers(SnifferManagerImpl.java:190)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.setupContainerInfos(ApplicationLifecycle.java:603)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:368)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:240)
    at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:389)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$1.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:348)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:363)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1085)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$1200(CommandRunnerImpl.java:95)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1291)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1259)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.doCommand(AdminAdapter.java:461)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.service(AdminAdapter.java:212)
    at com.sun.grizzly.tcp.http11.GrizzlyAdapter.service(GrizzlyAdapter.java:179)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.HK2Dispatcher.dispath(HK2Dispatcher.java:117)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$Hk2DispatcherCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:354)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:195)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:860)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:757)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1056)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:229)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
    at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)

GRAVE: Excepción al desplegar la aplicación
```

The rar file is generate when netbeans build the project and run with both application server this file exists, but only using glassfish show me that problem.

Please help me...

Thanks

Comment: Why are you deploying `.rar`? Didn't you mean `.war` or `.ear`?

Comment: Hi my friend, I am new in this project and do not know why that file is .rar, but in sun java system application server there is no any problem

Comment: Ok, so some thoughts - `DPL8004: file open failure` means what it says and is the source of subsequent nullpointer (it tries to use a file it could not read). Can you open that file in winrar/7zip/something? Can you rule out permissions problems? Finally (if both check out), would you be able to call `new JarFile(new File("path_to_your_file"))` in a sample program?

Comment: I can open the file and there is no permission problems, I will test the last suggestion, and write the result. Do you know some guide for doing this migration (from sun to glassfish 3)? I have not could find this information..Thanks